# leaving app on causes crash after a while

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a cocos2d game that, when I just leave it for awhile (amount of time varies: maybe 15-100 minutes) it crashes.  I don't have anything being called regularly that would eat up memory and I see no memory leak from instruments when app is left alone.  No exceptions are thrown and no error messages occur.

I receive a couple of memory warnings first, then the app crashes silently so I figure jetsam is killing the process.  Is their any way of avoiding this crash?  Oh, I am using xcode 4.2, ios 6 and an ipod touch 4s.

Comment: What's the error message when the crash occurs? It does seem like a memory leak.

Comment: There does not seem to be any memory leak or heap growth.  There is no error message.  It only seems to happen when run from xcode.

Comment: enable global exception breakpoint in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Are you disabling the rendering when the app goes background mode? Attempting to render after the phone goes to sleep will cause crashes.

Comment: No rendering occurs when player interaction is not occurring.  It is a turn based game.

Comment: Regardless of what you change or not, cocos2d renders all the time, unless you tell it not to. You need to tell CCDirector to stop the animation on the relevant appDelegate callbacks

Comment: Ok.  But it goes to sleep and wakes up fine.  It is the duration that matters.  By the way, is that best practice in cocos2d - to disable rendering when going to sleep.  How do I do this?